# Browsers Causing CPU Thrashing

Tags: windows-7, performance

Whether I use Chrome or IE my CPU starts to go crazy.  I'm not sure what kind of web content causes this.  Streaming?

[image]

I have a fresh install of Windows 7 x64 and I'm using IE 11 and Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m.  I have two cores.  Sometimes both look this way, and sometimes only one looks this way.

My machine becomes very slow when this phenomena occurs.  When I close my browser(s), then the problem goes away.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Comment: capture a xperf trace o the CPU usage of the browsers: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD (The Win8.1 SDK/WPT also works for your Win7).

Comment: have you captured the trace of the CPU usage so that I can help you?

Comment: @magicandre1981 The behavior has not yet re-occurred.  When it does I will perform the capture.